# Function not working on dynamic value but works on string, int or whatever I manually enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function, which formats phone numbers, that is exported like so :

```
export function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    var replace = ('' + phoneNumber).replace(/\D/g, '');
    var format = replace.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);

    return (!format) ? null : "(" + format[1] + ") " + format[2] + "-" + format[3];
}
```

and I am importing it into another file like so:

```
import {formatPhoneNumber} from '../ui/format_phone_number';
```

All is well and working, with the import. I wanted to mention that just in case there was some related issue.

I am looping over an object and want to format a phone number using the imported function. The odd thing is that when I try to format the value from the object, it returns `null`, but if I manually enter an `int`, or `string` it handles it correctly.

Here is my code:

```
$.each(signVendor, function( fieldId, value) {
    if(fieldId == 'phone') {
        console.log(value); // 262321345
        console.log(formatPhoneNumber(8885551234)); // (888) 555-1234
        console.log(formatPhoneNumber('8885551234')); // (888) 555-1234
        console.log(formatPhoneNumber(value)); // null
        value = formatPhoneNumber(value);
    }
    $formSignVendor.find('input[name=' + fieldId + ']').val(value);
 });
```

Here are the console results in the same order as above:

[image]

Comment: Did you try logging what you receive in the function or debugging it?

Comment: `3 + 3 + 4 !== "262321345".length`

Comment: In your example, that number does not match the regular expression.

Comment: @Andreas I assumed that the length was the same and that is what I get for assuming. Want to make that your answer so I can mark it? Thanks.